# How to configure GitLab CI job for running Gatling tests integrated with sbt?

Tags: scala, continuous-integration, gitlab, sbt, gatling

I applied sbt plugin for using Gatling and now I have no idea how to run my scenarios in GitLab CI.
Does somebody have such experience?

Comment: Hi! Welcome. Gonna need some more info to help you. Can you successfully run the sbt gatling tests locally? What does your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file look like?  What errors are you seeing in CI when it runs? etc.

Answer (score 4):

Resolved. How to run gatling scenarios in gitlab pipeline:

```
image: "hseeberger/scala-sbt:8u252_1.3.10_2.13.2"

stages:
  - testLoad

load:
  stage: testLoad
  when: manual
  script:
    - sbt gatling:test
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - "target/gatling/"
    expire_in: 1 week
    when: always
```

Answer (score 2):

The most plug-and-play solution is to use [FrontLine](https://gatling.io/gatling-frontline/), our Enterprise version.

Even though we don't have a plugin like we do for Jenkins, Bamboo and TeamCity, as GitLab CI doesn't provide a plugin API, we provide a shell script that implements the same load of FrontLine REST API calls.